# Android - Expandable menu to display common data

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-relativelayout

I have a screen which contains multiple fragments. In that i want to display the common data in all fragments. so i am looking for something like expandable menu (not from left side) to display in all fragments.

Actually its not a menu with divider, it has to just display some textviews and buttons

so on top of the screen, the menu should be expandable/collapsed for each fragments. Is there is any api is available in android to implement this?

Thanks
mindus

Comment: what about the ActionBar?

Comment: Sliding drawer would be a nice choice

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you want a list which could be expanded from edges and shown on all your fragments.

**Option 1:**

> You could use [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) but that does not support all
>   direction. For multiple direction, you could go with
>   [MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer](https://github.com/MiloTischler/Operation-Valkyrie/blob/master/Operation-Valkyrie/src/valkyrie/widget/MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer.java)

**Option 2**

> If you want a swiping type of menu, then you can also try
>   [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) which could be swipe from left and right.

**Option 3**

> You can also try the new [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) which was added in latest support library. It support swiping from all edges.